# Database revision needed for habit tracking database?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm trying to write a clean, maintainable, and easy to query database design for a habit tracking application.

Users can have habits, which have a goal of X minutes or repetitions every Y interval, along with a schedule for how often or which days this habit is required on.

[image]

The database has 6 main tables, which I'll briefly describe

- habit_groups
- habits (holds all habits, typically belonging to different users)
- habit_goals (holds the goal needed for completion)
- habit_progress_logs (stores committed effort towards goal)
- habit_schedules (used to set schedule, exclude days etc)

habit_schedules's recurrence column can have values like below in order to determine which days to include / exclude:

- RRULE:BYDAY=WE
- RRULE:BYDAY=WE,TH,FR
- RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=3

It created possibilities like so:

- Harry can complete 30 minutes of Reading every Thursday and Friday
- Jane can go for a bike ride twice a day, every day
- Peter can meditate every day of the week except Sundays
- Hannah does cooking once every 11 days

I have created an initial design, although it seems messy and difficult to query, especially in a sense of working out the progress of if a habit is completed, half done, understanding consecutive day streaks, and more.

To work out which habits are completed for a specific user I have to do something like this, which seems rather complex:

```
SELECT * FROM habits
INNER JOIN logmylife.habit_goals hg on habits.id = hg.habit_id
WHERE habits.user_id = 1 
  AND (SELECT SUM(value) 
       FROM habit_progress_logs 
       WHERE habit_progress_logs.created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL hg.`interval` SECOND) 
         AND habit_progress_logs.habit_id = habits.id
      ) > hg.value
```

It gets even more complicated when I have to ignore skips and/or failures, check schedules for excluded days (haven't even attempted yet), and more.

How can I make this structure better?

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/659c57c)

Comment: Will this system ever be used to for breaking bad habits or it's only for maintaining good ones?

Comment: In the future yes, although I'm looking to get it working efficiently with just good habits for now.

Comment: Understood. I ask because it may drive your design decision though, since that's a bit of the converse of use cases. For queries where you're looking to see if something happened (e.g. rows representing maintaining a good habit exist), you'll instead want to possibly check for the lack of something happening (e.g. rows for a bad habit occurrence don't exist).